# Error with __len__(self) function while creating Custom Dataset Object in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

I am following a video course for image classification and therein I have created a custom Dataset Class as follows:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class ChestXRayDataSet(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_dirs, transform):
        # Initialize the Object
        def get_image(class_name):
            # define a function to get images from the provided image directories
            images = [x for x in os.listdir(image_dirs[class_name]) if x.lower().endswith('png')]
            print(f'Found {len(images)} Images of Class {class_name}')
            return images
        
        # create a directory to store the images
        self.images = {}
        self.class_names = ['normal', 'viral', 'covid']
        
        for c in self.class_names:
            # store the images in directory with class names
            self.images[c] = get_image(c)
            
        self.image_dirs = image_dirs
        self.transform = transform
                    
        def __len__(self):
            # return the number of images in the dataset
            num_images = sum([len(self.images[class_name]) for class_name in self.class_names])
            return num_images
            
        def __getitem__(self, index):
            class_name = random.choice(self.class_names)
            index = index % len(self.images[class_name]) # to avoid index out of bound error
            image_name = self.images[class_name][index] # this is the selected images
            image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dirs[class_name], image_name)
            image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
            # Finally we return the example, and its index as required by
            # Dataset class
            return self.transform(image), self.class_names.index(class_name)
```

I create a Dataloader using this dataset as follows:

```
batch_size = 6
dl_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
```

as a result, I get the following Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_28/1549945295.py in <module>
      3 dl_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
      4 
----> 5 print('Num of Training Batches : ', len(dl_train))
      6 #print('Num of Test Batches : ', len(dl_test))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __len__(self)
    411         self._timeout = loader.timeout
    412         self._collate_fn = loader.collate_fn
--> 413         self._sampler_iter = iter(self._index_sampler)
    414         self._base_seed = torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_(generator=loader.generator).item()
    415         self._persistent_workers = loader.persistent_workers

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __len__(self)
    240         if self.drop_last:
    241             return len(self.sampler) // self.batch_size  # type: ignore
--> 242         else:
    243             return (len(self.sampler) + self.batch_size - 1) // self.batch_size  # type: ignore

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __len__(self)
     67         return iter(range(len(self.data_source)))
     68 
---> 69     def __len__(self) -> int:
     70         return len(self.data_source)
     71 

TypeError: object of type 'ChestXRayDataSet' has no len()
```

I am using Kaggle's notebook with Pytorch version 1.11.0+cpu to perform this task.

Help to resolve this error will be much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't the `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods indented too deep?

Comment: aaaahaa. You are a saver. And I am feeling embarrassed now. :$

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Kindly post it as an answer so that I may accept it.

Comment: **voting to close as due to a typo**. your indentation messed up the code. those methods are actually there, just not defined in the class but in the __init__, which breaks the code. -- such questions **should** be closed because they are _only_ useful to the one person that made the mistake, not anyone else. if anyone needs to debate this, there's guidance on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ as well as the [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__len__` and `__getitem__` method are indented too deeply, they should be at the same level as `__init__`.

Comment: you should vote to close as a typo, or flag to close as due to a typo.

Comment: I've never seen that, where can I find it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts -- I can't see if there's an actual "typo/unreproducible" option in the UI itself. there's some discussion here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310702/disputed-flag-typo-problem and here's more https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186366/how-to-flag-a-typo-question

Comment: It seems really unclear how to flag a question for a typo indeed, but I'll keep it in mind for next time.